# docker exec -it returns "cannot enable tty mode on non tty input"

Tags: centos, docker

`docker exec -it` command returns following error "cannot enable tty mode on non tty input"

```
level="fatal" msg="cannot enable tty mode on non tty input"
```

I am running docker(1.4.1) on centos box 6.6.
I am trying to execute the following command
`docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash`
but I am getting following error

```
level="fatal" msg="cannot enable tty mode on non tty input"
```

Comment: Is `containername` running with a terminal (`-t`)?

Comment: does `docker exec -i` works better than `docker exec -it` ?

Comment: @Andy - Didn't get you I am attempting to run the container using the command : docker exec -it ContainerName /bin/bash

Comment: @user2915097 Yes! -i works better :)

Answer (score 87):

Running `docker exec -i` instead of `docker exec -it` fixed my issue. Indeed, my script was launched by CRONTAB which isn't a terminal.

As a reminder:

```
Usage: docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container

  -i, --interactive=false    Keep STDIN open even if not attached  
  -t, --tty=false            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

Comment: Using -i or -t (or -it) I still had a problem. docker exec tty bug: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755 workaround there suggests using docker exec -it CONTAINER script -qc COMMAND. I'm running docker exec -it under jenkins jobs and getting error 'cannot enable tty mode on non tty input'.

Comment: Actually I found my problem traced back to how ssh under jenkins shell was done. Using ssh -T flag (disable pseudo tty generation) helped solve my problem.

Answer (score 14):

If you're getting this error in **windows docker client** then you may need to use the run command as below

`$ winpty docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash`

Comment: O/p is using docker on centos 6.6. Whilst this answer may solve similar issues on windows, It does not solve it on linux and in particular centos 6.6

Comment: @jonashdown, This solution is specifically for windows docker client and it is clearly specified in the content.

Comment: This command will run a new instance altogether of the image.

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows Docker. "The term `winpty` is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet."

Answer (score 9):

just use "-i"

> docker exec -i [your-ps] [command]

Answer (score 8):

If you're on Windows and using docker-machine and you're using GIT Bash or Cygwin, to "get inside" a running container you'll need to do the following:

`docker-machine ssh default` to ssh into the virtual machine (Virtualbox most likely)

`docker exec -it <container> bash` to get into the container.

EDIT:

I've recently discovered that if you use Windows PowerShell you can docker exec directly into the container, with Cygwin or Git Bash you can use `winpty docker exec -it <container> bash` and skip the `docker-machine ssh` step above.

Comment: This answer might solve the issue for windows users, but does not address the o/p's issue on centos 6.6

Answer (score 5):

I get "cannot enable tty mode on non tty input" for the following command on windows with boot2docker

```
docker exec -it <containerIdOrName> bash
```

Below command fixed the problem

```
winpty docker exec -it <containerIdOrName> bash
```

Answer (score 4):

`docker exec` runs a new command [in an already-running container](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec). It is not the way to start a new container -- use `docker run` for that.

That may be the cause for the "non tty input" error. Or it could be where you are running docker. Is it a true terminal? That is, is a full tty session available? You might want to check if you are in an interactive session with

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'
```

from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26676/how-to-check-if-a-shell-is-login-interactive-batch

Comment: Correct. I am running this command from Continous Integration Tool as( shell command). However when I run the same command on directly on the same machine's terminal window everything works find. When I ran the  [[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive' command on the terminal I got the response as Interactive but when I ran the same command on the same machine from CI tool i got Non-Interactive. How can I fix that?. it's a centos 6.6 box.

Comment: Regarding the "run" & 'exec', my container is already running. So when I do docker ps -a I see my container is running however when I try to Run a command in an existing container I get the above error. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hey user2118095, are you able to find any solutions, the same is happening for me.

Comment: @user2118095 did you get a solution for this? Would be great if you could share the solution if you were able to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same error message in Windows 7 64bit using Mintty shipped with Git for Windows. 

`$docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
 cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`

I tried to prefix the above command with winpty as other answers suggested but running it showed me another error message below:

`$ winpty docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
exec: "D:\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash": executable file not found in $PATH
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command not found or does not exist..`

Then I happened to run the following command which gave me what I want:

`$ winpty docker run -i -t ubuntu bash
root@512997713d49:/# ls
bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
root@512997713d49:/#`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running docker exec -it under jenkins jobs and getting error 'cannot enable tty mode on non tty input'. No output to docker exec command is returned. My job login sequence was:

```
jenkins shell -> ssh user@<testdriver> -> ssh root@<sut> -> su - <user> -> docker exec -it <container>
```

I made a change to use -T flag in the initial ssh from jenkins. "-T - Disable pseudo-terminal allocation". And use -i flag with docker exec instead of -it. "-i - interactive. -t - allocate pseudo tty.". This seems to have solved my problem.

```
jenkins shell -> ssh -T user@<testdriver> -> ssh root@<sut> -> su - <user> -> docker exec -i <container>
```

Behaviour kindof matches this docker exec tty bug: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755. Workaround on that docker bug discussion suggests using this:

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER> script -qc <COMMAND>
```

Using that workaround didn't solve my problem. It is interesting though. Try these using different flags and under different ssh invocations, you can see 'not a tty' even with using -t with docker exec:

```
$ docker exec -it <CONTAINER> script -qc 'tty'
/dev/pts/0
$ docker exec -it <CONTAINER> 'tty'            
not a tty
$ docker exec -it <CONTAINER> bash -c 'tty' 
not a tty
```