# docker exec command not executing in sh file

Tags: docker

When running below command in command line(terminal) this gets executed fine:

```
$sudo docker exec -it 5570dc09b58 bash
```

But same results with :

> FATA[0000] cannot enable tty mode on non tty input

Error when running in a shell script file.

Comment: Well, that makes sense; there is no terminal in a shell script. What are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Scripts may be forced to run in interactive mode with the -i option or with a `#!/bin/bash -i` header.

So adding shebang to the script with `-i` option should work:

```
#!/bin/bash -i

docker exec -it ed3d9e46b8ee date
```

Run the script as usual:

```
chmod +x run.sh
sudo ./run.sh
```

Output:

```
Thu Apr  2 14:06:00 UTC 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not running docker in a terminal, so you should remove `-t` from `-it`:

```
sudo docker exec -i 5570dc09b58 bash
```

See a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33528015/1515819).

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was using `-it` in jenkins `Execute Shell` but met this error. After I remove the `-t`, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few images which do not support the interactive shell/bash.
Example - Docker image mockserver/mockserver
[Docker Set Up](https://www.mock-server.com/where/docker.html)