# Run a docker command from Groovy script

Tags: groovy, docker

I have a some docker commands and i want to run them with a Groovy script (working under Ubuntu environment)

The following command works properly from the Terminal:

```
docker exec -it my_docker bash -c '/opt/someFolder/someScript.sh'
```

However, nothing happen when i run this command from the Groovy script:

```
['/bin/sh', '-c', "docker exec -it my_docker bash -c '/opt/someFolder/someScript.sh'"].execute().text.trim()
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Is it possible your process is writing to stderr instead of stdout?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably generating too much data on standard output, and so the buffer is getting full and the process blocks.

Instead of:

```
['/bin/sh', '-c', "docker exec -it my_docker bash -c '/opt/someFolder/someScript.sh'"].execute().text.trim()
```

Do:

```
def stdout = new StringWriter()
def stderr = new StringWriter()
['/bin/sh', '-c', "docker exec -it my_docker bash -c '/opt/someFolder/someScript.sh'"].execute().waitForProcessOutput(stdout, stderr)

println "OUTPUT: " + stdout.toString()
println "ERRORS: " + stderr.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to run your code, and got the following message: `ERRORS: cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`. Any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380344/docker-exec-it-command-returns-following-error-cannot-enable-tty-mode-on-non-t ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
docker exec -t my_docker bash -c '/opt/someFolder/someScript.sh'
```

Don't use `-ti`, just use `-t`.  You cannot have interaction when using `docker exec` to simply run a script, especially by any CI.