# Cannot pipe docker pid to bash command

Tags: shell, awk, docker, xargs

I commonly want to open a bash shell on a docker image. A multi-command process for this would be:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
bba983d72d48        scubbo/datenight    "apachectl -DFOREGROU"   7 days ago          Up 7 days           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   pensive_bell
$ docker exec -it bba983d72d48 bash
```

I'd like to shortcut this. However, I get the following error:

```
$ docker ps | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' | xargs -I {} docker exec -it {} bash
cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
```

From a little Googling, I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380344/docker-exec-it-returns-cannot-enable-tty-mode-on-non-tty-input) - however, if I drop the `-t` option, the command "completes" immediately.

I have confirmed that manually copy-pasting the output of `$ docker ps | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}'` into the appropriate position of `docker exec -it {} bash` is successful.

EDIT: Cutting out the `docker ps` from the pipe, the following also fails:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
4f20409c37b7        scubbo/datenight    "apachectl -DFOREGROU"   8 days ago          Up 8 days           0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   drunk_northcutt
$ docker ps -q
4f20409c37b7
$ echo '4f20409c37b7' | xargs -I {} docker exec -it {} bash
cannot enable tty mode on non tty input
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `docker ps -q` outputs only the ids of the running containers

If you have only one container launched, just do

`docker exec -it $(docker ps -q) bash`

if you want to enter the last launched container

`docker exec -it $(docker ps -lq) bash`

If you give a name to your container  when you launch it

`docker run --name nostalgic...`

then you can filter it with

`docker exec -it $(docker ps -q --filter "name=nostalgic") bash`

Check the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat set of commands! I'm still not sure why I can't pipe the id into `xargs docker exec`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I tend do this but I nest my commands

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}') bash
```

word of warning though, that you'll get errors if there's more than one container running.